# How to prevent a flex item from stretching when wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox, frontend

I am trying to create a grid system for my application using flexbox. I am having trouble when I use `flex-wrap: wrap` on the flex container.

In my example below, is it possible to prevent my header from stretching halfway down without specifying a height value? I would like for the header to be as high as the content within it and for the sidebar and content to stretch instead.

Any help would be appreciated.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100%;
}
.cell1 {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.cell2 {
  flex: 1 0 25%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.cell3 {
  flex: 1 0 75%;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell1">
    Header should be collapsed
  </div>
  <div class="cell2">
    Sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="cell3">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrapped flex row items are controlled using `align-content`, and since they "flex" horizontally you will need to wrap the _Sidebar/Content_ and have the `.container` flow set to `column` to be able to achieve what you ask for.

Comment: With the above you can set the wrapper to `flex: 1` and it will fill the remaining height properly.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I'm able to understand your problem `align-self: flex-start` should solve your problem. Update your header class CSS as:-

```
.cell1 {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  background-color: #eee;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: That won't make the _Sidebar/Content_ fill the remaining space, as flex row items doesn't "flex" vertically.

Answer (score -4):

I think it should be:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100%;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.cell1 {
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    background-color: #eee;
    height: auto;
}
.cell2 {
    flex: 1 0 25%;
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 100%;
}
.cell3 {
    flex: 1 0 75%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 100%;
}
```

So, just make sure you add height: auto to the header and height: 100% to the rest. This way, the first element will fit actual all needed height and rest elements will stretch to the container.

Comment: Nope, that will make the _Sidebar/Content_ overflow its parent. To solve OP's issue one need to change the markup a little.

Comment: Works fine for me, isn't it what OP needed? https://jsbin.com/xovediwudu/edit?html,css,output

Comment: It adds a scroll that shouldn't be there, and if you understand the concept of _fill the remaining space (stretch)_, you'll see your solution doesn't work.

Comment: I understand now, thanks.